# Javascript won't trigger not if nor else

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have JavaScript code that must move a *div* up and down. When I click it I want it to go up, then when I click the second time I want it to go down. My code is this:

```
function why()
{
    if (document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom == 23) {
        alert("I entered the IF");
        document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom = 0;
    }
    else {
        alert("I entered the ELSE");
        document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom = 23;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that the first time I click the div it goes up and tells me the ELSE part was executed, but after this, clicking it won't produce any effect, it wont go back down.  Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a unit, like `%` or `px` or whatever.

```js
function why() {

  if (document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom == '23px') {
    alert("I entered the IF");
    document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom = 0;
  } else {
    alert("I entered the ELSE");
    document.getElementById("newton").style.bottom = '23px';
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="newton" onclick="why()">click</button>
```

But I would toggle a class instead and put this change in CSS.

```js
function why(el) {
  el.classList.toggle('up');
}
```

```css
#newton {
  bottom: 0;
}
#newton.up {
  bottom: 23px;
}
```

```html
<button id="newton" onclick="why(this)">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if other js functions are wrong, it can affect my whole code,even other functions. The code was right, but since another function was wrong that made my code not work...Thanks for the toogle the class advice, I will implement it ;)